# Uncaught ReferenceError: <firebase string> is not defined at HTMLTableRowElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hey guys I created simple, dynamic table that reads data from Firebase. Here is the code for table:

```
userRef.on("child_added", snap => {
                 var username = snap.child("name").child("name").val();
                 var user_surname = snap.child("name").child("surname").val();
$("#user_table").append("<tr onClick=\"displayCos(" + user_surname + ")\"><td>"+ username +"</td></tr>")
```

as you can see, the table displays usernames and when i click on it i want to display user surname in `alert`, here's `displayCos` function code:

```
function displayCos(surname){
  if(surname != null){
  $("#surname_id").text(surname)
  }else {
  $("#surname_id").text("null");
 }
```

and here comes my error, when i'm clicking on username, debugger shows this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: (Here is user surname, let say: JOHNSON) is not defined at HTMLTableRowElement.onclick`. I also find out that when i change `username_surname` in firebase for something that contains letters and numbers the error looks like that: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`, and when the value is only numeric everything works fine.
I tried probably all solutions from StackOverflow and all of them aren't solution for my problem. I think that my value is not a string, as it should, sadly im new to jQuery and Javascript and can't figure it out only by myself, so I'm begging for help :)

@edit 
html code, without firebase details, if they're important i will update this:

```
<html lang="en">
 <head>

  <title>Wyplata</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

 </head>

 <body>

   <div id="login_div" class = "login-page">
     <div class = "form">
       <div class = "register-form">

         <input type = "text" placeholder="Imie" id="email_field"/>
         <input type = "text" placeholder="Hasło" id="password_field"/>
         <button onclick="login()" > Zaloguj </button>

       </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="company_div" class = "company-page">
    <div id="user_table" class = "userui">
      <button onclick="logout()" > Wyloguj </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you add in your question the HTML generated by your javascript?

Comment: Also, you mention "username_surname in firebase " but your code shows snap.child("name").child("surname").val();

Comment: Oh, no, ofcourse im changing "surname" value, it was just a little fail while i was writing this question.

Comment: What we should see is what is exactly injected in the div with id="user_table". Can you see it with the browser inspector? BTW, you should not inject some TRs directly into the div, without a <table> tag (it may work but it isn't correct HTML).

Comment: All that i can see from browser inspector is that, when im clicking on username whos surname is "Johnson", besides already  opened index.js file the browser inspector opens file called (index), and here is a line 1 with this: `displayCos(Johnson)`. "Johnson" is highlited and the error is: Uncaught ReferenceError: Johnson is not defined at HTMLTableRowElement.onclick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#user_table").append("<tr onClick=\"displayCos('" + user_surname + "')\"><td>"+ username +"</td></tr>")
```

See above. You should surround the user_name with quotes, in order to get `displayCos('Johnson')`.

If you get `displayCos(Johnson)` it means that Johnson is a variable name, and JavaScript tries to pass the value of this variable as argument of the displayCos function.

Comment: @Renuad Tarnec Thank you for your time :)

Comment: @BartSumps You are welcome. Also, as said above in the comments of your question, you should modify your code to <div class = "userui"><table id="user_table"></table><button onclick="logout()" > Wyloguj </button></div>. And also, when possible try to learn a framework like Vue.js which allows much more efficient and cleaner code.

Comment: I already changed the code, and ofcourse I will check the Vue.js. Thanks for the advices